# hover not working with font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

Here is some html and css. I need to show arrow on hover inside link, but I can't do this. How can I fix it?

```css
.header-text-links a {
  display: block;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fab608;
  color: #fab608;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Futura Demi";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: none;
}

.header-text-links a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #fab608;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header-text-links a:hover .header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class="header-text-links">
  <a class="header-text-links__works" href="#">Some text<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Also, I tried to get icon by classes .fas, .fa-arrow-right even try to get path tag, but the result is the same

Comment: If you tried that, please put it in the code so we know what code you're actually using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong selector...try `.header-text-links a:hover .svg-inline--fa`

**Why?**

For better understanding remove `:hover` for just once, so it will look like

```
.header-text-links a .header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa
```

which means it will target `.svg-inline--fa` inside `.header-text-links a` again inside `.header-text-links a`

```css
.header-text-links a {
  display: block;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fab608;
  color: #fab608;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Futura Demi";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: none;
}

.header-text-links a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #fab608;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header-text-links a:hover .svg-inline--fa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class="header-text-links">
  <a class="header-text-links__works" href="#">Some text<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Best solution**
Only change in css

```
.header-text-links a:hover > .svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```css
.header-text-links a {
 display: block;
 width: 278px;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid #fab608;
 color: #fab608;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Futura Demi";
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
 display: none;
}
.header-text-links a:hover {
 color: white;
 background: #fab608;
 text-decoration: none;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.header-text-links a:hover > .svg-inline--fa {
 display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class = "header-text-links">
<a class = "header-text-links__works" href = "#">Some text<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```